# How to ignore only space in select2.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

In input box when i type only spaces then its accepted and display blank with cross icon.
Please provide me a solution. How to handle it.

My code :

```
$("#userfrm #field_value").select2({
        maximumInputLength: 20,
        tags:tags,
        maximumSelectionSize : 10,
        createSearchChoice:function(term, data) { if ($(data).filter(function() { return this.text.localeCompare(term)===0; }).length===0) {return {id:term, text:term};} },
        multiple: true,
    });
```

Comment: Please share relevant html code also. And share jsfiddle which will be useful to help you

Comment: Please check this link and find keyoword with "Event Log"  http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can listen `select2-selecting` event to reject empty input:

```
$("#userfrm #field_value").select2({
    maximumInputLength: 20,
    tags: tags,
    maximumSelectionSize: 10,
    createSearchChoice: function(term, data) {
        if ($(data).filter(function() {
            return this.text.localeCompare(term) === 0;
        }).length === 0) {
            return {
                id: term,
                text: term
            };
        }
    },
    multiple: true,
})
.on('select2-selecting', function(e) {
    if (!$.trim(e.val)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/3Z64ZCBiIu8HU5hnAFI7?p=preview